# What is the first argument to PackageLoader for in Python's jinja module

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

Okay so I have the following, I only want to know what "yourapplication" is. It's supposed to be a module, but a module that does what?

The website is down so there's currently no way I can look up how to instantiate a new Jinja based project

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication'))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As I mentioned the website was down, it's back up now.